# Mudar a cor de fundo da ActionBar com TabActivity

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Estou com problemas para alterar o `background`.

Quando uso desse jeito, com o `extends` do `TabActivity`:

```
public class HomeTabActivity extends TabActivity {...
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBar _actionBar;    
}
```

Não consigo dar um `getSupportActionBar();` pra depois eu mudar a cor. Tem algum outro jeito de mudar?

Comment: O `getSupportActionBar` pertence a `ActionBarActivity`, lembrando que o `TabActivity` foi depreciado. Acho que você pode trocar essa herança sem problemas.

Comment: Posso colocar `ActionBarActivity` sem problemas?

Comment: Sim, de acordo com a documentação (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).

Comment: @Wakim, pode fazer uma resposta pra eu marcar como correta?

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é sua activity herdar de ActionBarActivity.

depois, você pega getSupportActionBar() e adiciona as tabs.

Veja a documentação:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html